# Add a HTML Page To WordPress Site Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I'm creating a plugin that will add a custom page to the website (with no template).

I'm struggling to work out how talk to WordPress from inside the Jquery part of my plugin.

At present, there is a variable called res that contains all the HTML for the page.

```
$.post( templateUrl + "templates/template2.html", function( data ) {
    tinyMCE.triggerSave();
    var res = data.replace("[([PREHEADER])]", $("#peg-newsletter-preheader").val())  
    res = res.replace("[([HEADING])]", $("#peg-newsletter-heading").val());
});
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are using post incorrectly.
This section of the function

```
     function( data ) {
                tinyMCE.triggerSave();
                var res = data.replace("[([PREHEADER])]", $("#peg-newsletter-preheader").val())  
                res = res.replace("[([HEADING])]", $("#peg-newsletter-heading").val());
            })
```

is a call back (meaning this is a response you get from WP after you make a successful post).  Changing values here only changes the values that you receive rather than wp.

To 'talk' to wp you need to post the data in the body: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

So your jquery post will look like this:

```
$.post( templateUrl + "templates/template2.html", 
      { preHeader: "something", Header: "something" }, 
      function( data ) {
         alert("Post successful");
      });
```

However this would assume that your end point allow for a post request to do what you want.

I am not sure what you are trying to achieve though.  It looks like you want to change the HTML template of WP?  If so I don't know of any rest api that would allow you to do that, as these api's are primarily for pulling WP Posts/Blog data from WP.  HTH